# Backing up thunderbird from win to linux

Tags: windows, linux, thunderbird

I'm planning to format this laptop soon and although the e-mail is from google and all my mails is there, re-downloading is kinda out of the question since it takes hours to finish. I want to back-up my thunderbird, which folder should I back-up and where to place it in linux?

Another thing is that I want to use Evolution mail, loving the progress they've done so far, is it possible to import from thunderbird to evo?

Comment: Did a quick search and found these two links for you: http://fosswire.com/post/2008/03/migrate-your-thunderbird-emails-from-windows-to-linux/ and http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Applications_GUI_Multimedia/Howto_migrate_from_Thunderbird_to_Evolution

Comment: cheers, i tried to google it up but the explanations weren't exactly crystal clear.

Comment: @allenskd were you able to get this to work?